# FIWARE - Orion Context Broker offset parameter behaviour

Tags: fiware-orion

I am facing the following problem regarding FIWARE Orion Context Broker, I hope someone has an idea about it.

I store records in FIWARE Orion CB, version 1.2.0, running in a Docker instance and in one type I receive the following response after posting a GET call to http://mywebsite.eu:1016/v2/types/MyTYPE

```
{
    "attrs": {
        "cid": {
            "types": [
                "String"
            ]
        },
        "datetime": {
            "types": [
                "String"
            ]
        },
        "humidity": {
            "types": [
                "Float"
            ]
        },
        "luminosity": {
            "types": [
                "Integer"
            ]
        },
        "temperature": {
            "types": [
                "Float"
            ]
        }
    },
    "count": 55811
}
```

As you can see the “count” is 55811. But, when I send another GET call to http://mywebsite.eu:1026/v2/entities?type=MyTYPE&offset=54908&limit=1, I receive the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": ".*",
        "type": "MyTYPE"
    }
]
```

From that number of offset (54908) and up, the response is the same. I’ve checked space in my server and there is plenty of it, so it is not a matter of disk space. I’ve checked that data is going to Orion CB the same way as before from my Raspberries. So, my question is if there is an upper limit for records per type that Orion can store and when this limit is reached I should change type. Maybe there is something that I am missing and any advice you can give me will help me a lot.

Comment: Orion 1.2.0 is a bit old, it has been overpassed by newer versions (in particular Orion 1.3.0 included a lot of bugfixes). Would it be feasible to upgrade to a newest Orion version (as the newest one in the moment of writting this: 1.5.0) in order to check if the problem happens with it? Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you could self-answer your own question, in order to describe the solution to other potential users with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: I am really sorry I had to delete my previous comment. It seems like the problem isn't solved finally. I had that impression at the beggining but as data keep arriving to Orion the problem arised again. I have the feeling that it is caused to MongoDB version. Anyway, I thank you again @fgalan for your help and I will come back when, hopefully, I will reach to a certain solution.

Comment: @fgalan unfortunatelly, the problem isn't resolved. I realized that when the sum of records of same type exceeds a specific volume, then Orion refuse to return any results. More specifically, if records of "MyType" are 55000 for example and volume of all these records is larger than 31.5 MB, then Orion won't return any records after 55000. The only solution I see is to "hit" directly mongodb from my code, but Orion is supposed to do that. Any clues? Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I would need to have a look to a dump of your database (i.e. the one that `mongodump` provides) to debug on this. Would it be feasible?

Comment: Of course it is. Where would you like me to sent it to you?

Comment: If there isn't any problem to publish them (e.g. due to confidenciality issues) then I'd recommed to publish it in any Internet service able to do so (e.g. dropbox) then provide the link in this thread so I can donwload.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpx6hrysg2uy9lf/orion.20161202.archive.zip?dl=0   Please let me know when you download it so to delete it from dropbox. Thank you very much in advance for your help, I appreciate. In case you attend the FIWARE summit in Malaga, I hope to have an opportunity to discuss about Orion in person :-)

Comment: I have it, with this MD5SUM: 94aafd21f261385ad2ed330ec27506d1. If correct, you can delete it from dropbox.

Comment: Btw, which command have you used for generating it? I'm having some problems trying to restore unsing `mongorestore`...

Comment: Maybe this link from Orion documentation regading backup up its database may help: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/database_admin/index.html#backup

Comment: I used mongodump and saved it in archive file. I specified the database (orion). If you cannot restore it, let me know so I give it another try.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot recover dump from that file. Please, generate again using the following command `mongodump --db orion && tar cfvz orion.tgz dump/` and uploading the resulting `oriong.tgz` file. Thx!

Comment: Hello again @fgalan. This is the link for the new mongodump file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wao6se18bofg1rh/orion.tgz?dl=0 Let me know when you have downloaded it. Thank you again very much for your help.

Comment: I have downloaded, imported (you can remove it from dropbox) and done some tests with Orion 1.2.3 (not exactly the 1.2.0 you cite but basically equivalent from a functional point of view). The result is here: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/31cb3f502e8c48c743575923594fb01b. I haven't used "MyTYPE" literarly as it is not one of the existing types, but the "ASN" type which have a large number of entities (54879). I haven't found any problem, but maybe I'm doing some different step. Could you edit your question post to show the *exact* requests that reproduce the problem on that DB dump, pls?

Comment: Exactly, the "ASN" type is the one with the most records. Actually, the Orion version I use is not 1.2 but 1.5 (I upgraded it after your recommendation) but the result is the same in both versions. Try to perform a get call to Orion, in the following fashion: http://some.ip:1026/v2/entities?type=ASN&limit=1&offset=54879 and you will receive nothing as a result. If you insert more records in "ASN" type, and perform calls with that offset, again you will receive no proper results. That is the actual problem. Orion won't return proper results after a specific offset number.

Comment: It is normal that `GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&offset=54879&limit=1` returns nothigs. I have added a comprensive answer explaining how offset works that I hope helps to clarify (in negative case, let's continue the dicussion :)

Comment: By the way, I'll be attending to the FIWARE Summit (I'm one of the speakers in three talks ;). I hope we have the opportunity to meet in person.

Comment: That is great! Looking forward to meeting you at the Summit. First of all to thank you in person for the valuable help you gave me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been observed that with large offset values you may get the following effect:

- The response you get is the one that the question post mentions, e.g.:

  ```
  [
      {
          "id": ".*",
          "type": "ASN"
      }
  ]
  ```
- An error message like this one appears in Orion logs:

  ```
  Raising alarm DatabaseError: nextSafe(): { $err: "Executor error: OperationFailed Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.", code: 17144 }
  ```

The solution is creating an index in the DB field used for sorting. In the case of default ordering (based on creation date) the index can be created at Mongo shell as follows (assuming that `orion` is the name of the DB your are using):

```
$ mongo
> use orion
> db.entities.createIndex({creDate: 1})
```

In fact, it uses to be a good idea to create the indexes described [in this section in the documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/perf_tuning/index.html#database-indexes).

**EDIT**: the response is not the proper one: Orion should response using a 500 Internal Server Error with a descriptive message about the problem. This fix is ready to land in master branch and will be included in Orion 1.7.0 (to be released by the early 2017).

Comment: Currently, the response is not correct in this case: it should be a 500 Internal Server Error with a descriptive message about it. An issue has been created at Orion repository and soon will be addressed: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2752

Comment: By creating an index in mongodb solved the problem. I am happy it will be resolved in the new Orion version. I would like to thank you very much @fgalan for your help. This problem was a real trouble for long time and I feel relieved it is resolved. I am already updating my application according to your directions. Thank you again!

Comment: Great! If the answer has been useful, please provide a +1 and accept it as correct at SOF. It is not to feed my ego :) but to show to other users with similar problems that the answer is a right solution.

Comment: I did that the moment I saw a successful result. The problem is that stackoverflow doesn't allow my to vote until I reach a reputation level of 15 :(

Answer (score 0):

The offset parameter means how many elements have to be skipped before returning results. Thus, offset=0 (the defaulf value if offset parameter is ommited) means to start in the first element, offset=1 means to start in the second element, an so.

Let's consider the ASN type, which has 54879 entities (as `GET /v2/types/ASN` shown). Using offset=0 we get the first entity (which happens to be the one with id `1470515373636_1`):

```
GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&limit=1

[
  {
    "id": "1470515373636_1"
    ...
  }
]
```

Let's use now offset 54878 (equal to the total number of ASN entities minus one). That is, skipping the first 54878 entities only the last one remains (which id happens to be `1480344938807_1`):

```
GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&offset=54878&limit=1

[
  {
    "id": "1480344938807_1"
    ...
  }
]
```

Note that if we use offset equal to the total number of entities (or any greater number), i.e. 54879, that means that all the entities have been skipped. In other words, we are going beyond the limit. Thus is is normal that in that case Orion return an empty list of entities:

```
GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&offset=54879&limit=1

[]
```

Another "consistency" check: if you invert the order (by default, entities are ordered by increasing creation date, i.e. from older to newer, but you can change that using the `orderBy` parameter) you can check that the former first element is now the last and viceversa. In particular, `orderBy=!dateCreated` orders results by decreasing creation date (i.e. from  newer to older).

Thus, now searching for the first element return the former last (i.e. `1480344938807_1`)

```
GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&limit=1&orderBy=!dateCreated

[
  {
    "id": "1480344938807_1"
    ...
  }
]
```

and searching for the last element return the former last (i.e. `1470515373636_1`)

```
GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&offset=54878&limit=1&orderBy=!dateCreated

[
  {
    "id": "1470515373636_1"
    ...
  }
]
```

Let's do another test. Let's add a new ASN entity, just for fun:

```
POST /v2/entities?options=keyValues

{
  "id": "TestingEntity",
  "type": "ASN",
  "A": 42
}
```

so, now the total number of entities in the ASN type is 54880. The new entity is the last one to be created, so it will be put at the end with default ordering (i.e. increasing creation date). You can check it with the following query:

```
GET /v2/entities?type=ASN&offset=54879&limit=1

[
  {
    "id": "TestingEntity"
    ...
  }
]
```

Note that that query returned `[]` before adding the new entity (see above).

In sum, Orion Context Broker behaviour seems to be as expected with regard to offset parameter. You say that the problem was Orion won't return proper results after a specific offset number, but note that empty results is a proper result if your offset has passed beyond the total number of elements.

Comment: First, I would like again to thank you very much for your efforts to help me. Unfortunately, this is not the actuall problem. Try to add two-three more entities in the ASN type and perform a GET call to return the last one. There, you will see that it will not return what it is supposed to. On the contrary, if you do the same inside mongo shell you will get the correct result. It looks like that Orion after a certain amount of entities with same type, refuses to return any of them after a specific number which (maybe) is depended of the sum volume of all same type entities.

Comment: I think I have hit the problem after adding 5 more entities... I'll deal with it in an independent answer.